# Concatenate Django Settings "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES"

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-settings

I want to import the django default settings, using `from django.conf import global_settings`, and then add `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to it. I like to do this with my settings so that I know what I have added and what is default. So my settings file would look like this:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
...
global_settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )
```

This strategy works for other settings, such as `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, but when I try it, it isn't working. I added `print global_settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` after adding the Debug Toolbar Middlware and this was my output when using `runserver`

```
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'canada.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

If you scroll over you can see that it runs through the settings twice. The second time it adds the setting again. How can I prevent this? To I have to just hard code my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in the settings? Also is there a good reason not to import the default django settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's recommended that you make changes directly to global_settings variable. The Django core does a lot of screwing around with it as it merges in all the stuff you define in settings.py, so it may be that your changes are getting overwritten.

If you really want to derive your variables from global_settings directly, I'd make a local copy, then modify that. Example:

```
GLOBAL_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = global_settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
LOCAL_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = GLOBAL_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + LOCAL_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```

Django should then pick up that you've defined a new version of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, and insert it into global_middleware using the proper process.

This being said, I personally would prefer to have all the middleware classes there for me to see and re-arrange if needed. By using the method you've chosen, you don't know what could change between Django revisions!

Comment: I agree about rearranging. I think it would be better to list them all.